# transfer from wordpress to drupal > profile form not working

Tags: drupal, profile

My "Sign up for newsletter" form was working on Wordpress. I recently moved to Drupal and now I am getting the error message below. Of the 4 possible errors, the profile is enabled, there is a Profile with that ID.

So the problem seems to be either the Profile is "not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings" or there is a permissions problem.

How do I resolve either of these in Drupal?

The requested Profile (gid=15) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile with that ID OR you do not have permission to access this profile. Please contact the site administrator if you need assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> either the Profile is "not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings"

this is resolved in Drupal in exact same way as WP, in the Settings section of the Profile

> or there is a permissions problem

I don't assume you are asking 'where do I set permissions in Drupal' but that seems like the only answer I can give - look under People in the drupal admin menu. If the Profile contains custom fields then make sure you have also set the permission for these, but in theory these are all much the same in WP I believe

Otherwise happy to try answering again if you can finesse your question.